# SignalR - Broadcast to all clients except Caller

Tags: signalr

Is there a way to send a message to all connected clients except the client that is sending the message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2014 you can [select clients](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients) with Hubs.

The **Others** property publishes to all clients except the calling client.

```
Clients.Others.addContosoChatMessageToPage(name, message);
```

Answer (score 4):

Not yet, the only thing you can do today is filter on the client side.